# Installing Ubuntu server 12.04 on VMware Workstation 8 in an Ubuntu 12.04 desktop

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, vmware-workstation

I've got an Ubuntu desktop 64bit with a VMware workstation 8 installed on it and now I'm trying to install an Ubuntu server 12.04.2 64bit as a VM but it prompts error and stops.

Here's the error:

```
Unable to install the selected kernel
An error was returned while trying to install the kernel into the target system.
Kernel package: 'linux-generic-lts-quantal'.
Check /var/log/syslog or see virtual console 4 for details.
```

Afterwards it goes to `Ubuntu installer main menu` and I used the shell access `ash` to read the `/var/log/syslog` to look for the error. Here's what I found (even though I have no idea what I'm looking for!):

```
in-target: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

And a couple of lines later:

```
base-installer: error: exiting on error base-installer/kernel/failed-install
```

Can someone tell me what's going on? I've just downloaded the `ISO` file for Ubuntu server using Torrent and I will download it once again from their website later even though I don't think the file is damaged as it gets opened with `Archive Manager` successfully!

**[UPDATE]**

I've tested the same `ISO` image file with `AQEMU` and faced the same results.

I've also noticed that the image file I'm **downloading directly from Ubuntu's website** is `12.04.3` while the one from torrent is `12.04.2`.

We shall see if this new image file will work in few hours (it's the second time I'm downloading it as the first time failed with a 404 error).

**[UPDATE]**

I've just downloaded 12.04.3 from *torrent* and it works fine. The problem was either the 12.04.2 or my version was damaged!

Comment: I'd be very interested to know how the installation goes using an iso direct from ubuntu's website.

Comment: It will take few hours before it is downloaded, but I'll post it for sure.

Comment: To clarify for others who may be having your issue, can you verify that the image you finally installed was the 12.04.3 ISO from Ubuntu's website? Thank you!

Comment: Based on the network error and best practices you should check your ISO files md5 prior to installing.

Comment: Please write up your solution as an answer so that others may benefit from your experience. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just downloaded 12.04.3 from torrent and it works fine. The problem was either the 12.04.2 or my version was damaged!